# How can I make my web server auto update from my repo?

Tags: git, directory, repo

I have a bitbucket repo that holds all of my website's files needed to run my personal site. Is there a way to make that local folder on my web server pc sync to my repo automatically when I make changes to my master branch? I am currently using a USB stick to merge changes between PCs and it is more work.

TLDR; Basically, I want to Code > Submit to master > Load site from webserver on chrome > Changes present.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at github actions. I use these to make sure every commit I make hasn't regressed anything through building and running unit tests. It's also fairly simple to automate the deploy process.

https://github.com/features/actions

Comment: I will take a look. I just looked more into this also. I realized that I can just install git on my Linux server then have a bash script that runs my sync commands and have that repo's path be set to the Linux server's file path. Easy! Ha. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitbucket pipelines (bitbucket version of github action) to automate your deploy process:

- go to https://bitbucket.org/USER/REPO/admin/addon/admin/pipelines/settings
- enable pipeline (click on the switch)
- create file `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` in your repo, example content:

```yaml
image: atlassian/default-image:2
pipelines:
branches:
  master:
    - parallel:
      - step:
          name: 'Automated Deployment'
          script:
            - curl https://your.web.server.com/automated_deployment.php
```

- assume in your deployment web server you have `automated_deployment.php` which have such content:

```php
<?php
shell_exec('cd /var/www/myproject && git pull');
```

Such setup means that:

- whenever you pushed to master OR when changes merged from PR to master, bitbucket will run command: `curl https://your.web.server.com/automated_deployment.php`
- the command will call `automated_deployment.php` in your web server, which will call `cd /var/www/myproject && git pull`
- this assumes you use php in your deployment server. For other kind of setup (e.g.: python/flask/django/node.js), you should read their respective way to execute shell/os command

#### Possible improvement:

- store URL `https://your.web.server.com/automated_deployment.php` in bitbucket repository variable (so identical `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` files may be used for multiple projects)
- verify client certificate for this `automated_deployment.php` (so not everyone on the internet can call `https://your.web.server.com/automated_deployment.php` on your server (or simply use a secret password)
- verify that newest commit hash in bitbucket is identical to newest commit hash in your production server